# How to stretch delimiters to envolve matrices inside of a kbordermatrix?

Tags: kbordermatrix

I am putting three matrices inside of a kbordermatrix, but the delimiters do not envolve the inner matrices completely. How can I do to stretch the kbordermatrix delimiters to envolve the inner matrices?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[brazil]{article}



\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,array,mathtools}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}



\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray} 
    \mathbf{A} & = & 
    \setlength{\kbrowsep}{2pt}
    \setlength{\kbcolsep}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}
    \renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}
    \kbordermatrix{
        \omit & & , & & , & \cr
        \omit & \overbrace{\begingroup
            \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}
            \begin{bmatrix}
            0,9960 & -0,0037    \\
            0,0111 &  0,9867        
            \end{bmatrix}
            \endgroup} & , & \overbrace{\begingroup
            \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}
            \begin{bmatrix}
            0,9961 & -0,0059    \\
            0,0715 &  1,0423
            \end{bmatrix}
            \endgroup} & , & \overbrace{\begingroup
            \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}
            \begin{bmatrix}
            1,0034 & 0,0009     \\
            0,0098 & 0,9696
            \end{bmatrix}
            \endgroup}
    } \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}


\end{document}
```

The execution results of aforementioned code:

[image]

P.S.: I would like to stretch the delimiters until the red arrows.

Comment: What's the purpose of those commas hanging from nowhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need `kbordermatrix` to obtain this layout. However, the matrix in the last  column can't have an `overbrace`, so I added a `\vphantom` of a similar matrix.

I also propose a variant with inner medium-sized matrices, with the `mmatrix` environment from `nccmath`.  Last, I had to load `icomma` to have a correct spacing of the decimal comma.

```
\documentclass[brazil]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, array, mathtools}
\usepackage{icomma, nccmath} 
\newenvironment{bmmatrix}{\medsize\bmatrix}{\endbmatrix\endmedsize}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{A} & = \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
 \begin{pmatrix}
            \,\smash[t]{\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
            0{,}9960 & -0,0037 \\
            0,0111 & 0,9867
            \end{bmatrix}}}
 &\negthickspace{,}\negthickspace\! & 
            \smash[t]{\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
            0,9961 & -0,0059 \\
            0,0715 & 1,0423
            \end{bmatrix}}}
 &\negthickspace{,}\negthickspace\! & 
            {\smash[t]{\overbrace%
            {\begin{bmatrix}
            1,0034 & 0,0009 \\
            0,0098 & 0,9696
            \end{bmatrix}}}}\, \vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}\, \\ \,
  \end{bmatrix}}
 \end{pmatrix}\\[2ex]\ 
\mathbf{A} & = \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{pmatrix}
            \,\smash[t]{\overbrace{\begin{bmmatrix}
            0{,}9960 & -0,0037 \\
            0,0111 & 0,9867
            \end{bmmatrix}}}
 &\negthickspace{,}\negthickspace\! &
            \smash[t]{\overbrace{\begin{bmmatrix}
            0,9961 & -0,0059 \\
            0,0715 & 1,0423
            \end{bmmatrix}}}
 &\negthickspace{,}\negthickspace\! &
            {\smash[t]{\overbrace%
            {\begin{bmmatrix}
            1,0034 & 0,0009 \\
            0,0098 & 0,9696
            \end{bmmatrix}}}}\, \vphantom{\begin{bmmatrix}\, \\ \,
  \end{bmmatrix}}
 \end{pmatrix}
 \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really wanted to work with kbordermatrix, but your solution is interesting. I did not understand why you used the negthickspace and the smash commands.

Comment: The negthickspace is just for æsthetic reasons – so it's only a matter of personal taste. As to `\smash[t]`, it is  to ensure the three braces are *above* the external parentheses.

Comment: You should compensate the `\smash` with a `\vphantom`, or the braces would not be taken into consideration for vertical spacing.

Comment: @egreg: That's right, but I have no context. If it's a new line in a multiline equation, a simple `\\[2ex]`, for instance, might do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Turn off `\arraystretch`.  Then, manually, add the desired space between rows.

```
\documentclass[brazil]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,array,mathtools}
\usepackage{kbordermatrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqnarray} 
    \mathbf{A} & = & 
    \setlength{\kbrowsep}{2pt}
    \setlength{\kbcolsep}{0pt}
%    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}
    \renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}
    \kbordermatrix{
        \omit & & , & & , & \cr
        \omit & \overbrace{\begingroup
            \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}
            \begin{bmatrix}
            0,9960 & -0,0037    \\[2ex]
            0,0111 &  0,9867        
            \end{bmatrix}
            \endgroup} & , & \overbrace{\begingroup
            \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}
            \begin{bmatrix}
            0,9961 & -0,0059    \\[2ex]
            0,0715 &  1,0423
            \end{bmatrix}
            \endgroup} & , & \overbrace{\begingroup
            \setlength{\arraycolsep}{2.5pt}
            \begin{bmatrix}
            1,0034 & 0,0009     \\[2ex]
            0,0098 & 0,9696
            \end{bmatrix}
            \endgroup}
    } \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @StevenSegletes, I tested your solution and it worked fine. Thank you by help.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that `kbordermatrix` is the wrong tool for the job.

I suggest using `siunitx` for numeric tables.

Here the trick is to use a phantom two-line array in order to set the left and right delimiters. The definitions are made inside `\[...\]`, so they are local to it.

If you have an alignment, the local definitions should be arranged differently, but it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

In any case, **never** use `eqnarray` (see [`eqnarray` vs `align`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196)).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,array,mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\newenvironment{nmatrix}[1]
 {\begin{bmatrix}\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}}
 {\end{tabular}\end{bmatrix}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[3]
\[
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\newcommand{\LEFT}{%
  \left(\vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}}\right.
}
\newcommand{\RIGHT}{%
  \left.\vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}}\right)
}
%% Now the real job
\mathbf{A}=
\LEFT
\overbrace{
  \begin{nmatrix}{T{1.4}T{-1.4}}
  0,9960 & -0,0037    \\
  0,0111 &  0,9867        
  \end{nmatrix}
}\;,\;
\overbrace{
  \begin{nmatrix}{T{1.4}T{-1.4}}
  0,9961 & -0,0059    \\
  0,0715 &  1,0423
  \end{nmatrix}
}\;,\;
\overbrace{
  \begin{nmatrix}{T{1.4}T{1.4}}
  1,0034 & 0,0009     \\
  0,0098 & 0,9696
  \end{nmatrix}
}
\RIGHT
\]
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really would like to use the kbordermatrix, because this package has the left  and upper sides options to use as explainations of lines and columns. I know bordermatrix, but I read in kborderdermatrix documentation that kbordermatrix is an improvement version to bordermatrix. Is there any alternative as simmilar as  kbordermatrix?